# GraphQL Error - "The type of Mutation.createFriend(input:) must be Input Type but got: Friend."

Tags: graphql

Here is my Graphql schema:

```
type Friend {
        id: ID
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        gender: String
        email: String
    }

    type Query {
        friend: Friend
    }

    input FriendInput {
        id: ID
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        gender: String
        email: String
    }

    type Mutation {
        createFriend(input: FriendInput): Friend
    }
```

The culprit is the `createFriend` mutation. When I run the code, I get this error:
"The type of Mutation.createFriend(input:) must be Input Type but got: Friend."

Am I getting the syntax wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how used/called/what code? input type usually doesn't contain `id` (created on BE/result of mutation)

Comment: That fixed it! I took the id out of the input.